# Dynamic SASS variables from a server side language

Tags: dynamic, build, sass, gulp

I have a database table that contains a list of colour variables (example HEX colour code). My styles are compiled using Gulp and SASS.

When my Django app creates/updates a row in the database i need to build a new stylesheet based on the colours. 
Somehow i need to get the colours from my server side app into a build process.

```
Record with colours added -> Gulp runs -> New colour variables are used within the stylesheet generation.
```

Any ideas how this could be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried anything?  *Anything* at all?

Comment: I've made various build processes before, but never transporting in vars. I am looking for a point in the right direction by someone who may have solved this problem before. Edit - I also have seen various data inject techniques in the Gulp build process, but none seem to fit the model. Gulp-data being the more promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem in a less than ideal way..

There is a module called [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess) which take a context array and replaces vars before the sass process runs..

For example:

**SASS File**

```
$body-background: '/* @echo body-background */';

body {
  background: $body-background;
}
```

**GULP**

```
var data = {
    '1': {
        'body-background': '#f00',
    },
    '2': {
        'body-background': '#ffffff',
    }
}

gulp.task('scss', function () {

    for (var partner_id in data) {
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(partner_id)) continue;
        var partner_data = data[partner_id]

        gulp.src('./static/scss/*.scss')
            .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe($.preprocess({context: partner_data}))
            .pipe($.sass({
                    errLogToConsole: true,
                    style: 'compact'
                })
                .on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log('Error:', err);
                    this.emit('end');
                }))
            .pipe($.autoprefixer({cascade: false}))
            .pipe($.cssnano())
            .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/css/'+ partner_id))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this service https://www.grooveui.com, that lets you create multiple themes from your SASS files.

The only catch is you have to host your SASS files with them. Then you can create new themes and set variable values. I guess they are using database to store variables and generating multiple SASS files.

Could be worth a try.